# How to use labeled fields in Kibana search or in visualization/dashboard

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, searchable

I had labeled fields from SAR report for CPU utilization and now those are showing in the kibana dashboard. However, when i try to build dashboard or visualization graph on that , its not working . After studying about it , I found that the filed type is "text" , however, it should be "keyword" to make those searchable .
I tried updating the field type to "keyword" using below JSON execution , but its failing

```
PUT filebeat-2018.10.21
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "cpu": {
          "type":  "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Resource already exist exception is coming while updating the type

```
"type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [filebeat-2018.10.21/8bBXsKl2TZeI1pegRRY9yw] already exists"
```

Please guide me how to update the type to "keyword" ( or Number if that makes it searchable ).
Below is the index mapping

```
{
  "filebeat-2018.10.21": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "beat": {
            "properties": {
              "hostname": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "version": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "blocked": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "commit": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "cpu": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "idle": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "iowait": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbactive": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbbuffers": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbcached": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbcommit": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbdirty": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbinact": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbmemfree": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "kbmemused": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ldavg1": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ldavg15": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ldavg5": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "load_time": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "memused": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "nice": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "plistsz": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "runqsz": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "steal": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "system": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "time_12": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1540080004528",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "ab8bBXs12LmNBa123egRRdf123Y9yw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6040299"
        },
        "provided_name": "filebeat-2018.10.21"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, please guide me if there is a way by which any new fields I map in logstash should go with type "keyword".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query block is failing because you are trying to add an index with a mapping but that index already exists.

Unfortunately, you cannot change the mapping type of an existing field in an index. You should create a new index with correct mapping and reindex your data.

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) link, mapping for existing fields cannot be updated. Only new properties & multi-fields can be added. Few mapping parameters such as `enabled`, `ignore_above` can be updated on existing fields.